# using xpath to select an attribute with a dash in the value

Tags: xpath, xquery, exist-db

I'm using exist-db to parse XML documents. I am writing a xquery script to process the documents.

### My XML input looks something like this

```
<data>   
<schedules>
<schedule>
<event date="2015-08-28"/>
<event date="2015-08-29"/>
</schedule>
</schedules>
</data>
```

I want to use xquery/xpath to select all events where event/@date = "2015-08-28".

### I tried this

```
let $rawDoc := collection("/db/test")/data/schedules/schedule[event/@date = "2015-08-28"]
```

### but I get back this

```
<data>   
<schedules>
<schedule>
<event date="2015-08-28"/>
<event date="2015-08-29"/>
</schedule>
</schedules>
</data>
```

### when I want this

```
<data>   
<schedules>
<schedule>
<event date="2015-08-28"/>
</schedule>
</schedules>
</data>
```

it seems like the presence of the "-" in either the date attribute value or my query string is not being treated as an explicit dash. It isn't clear to me how to escape the "-"? I tried "-" and that didn't work (no results returned).

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Ty

Comment: If you select for `/data/schedules/schedule[...]` you're going to get the entire contents of that element, which will include any descendant `event` elements. Maybe instead select on `event` elements? Or why do you need the `schedule` element?

Comment: Your theory that it has something to do with the hyphens is about as wild as a conjecture that it depends on the phase of the moon.

Comment: Did either answer below help? Please mark one as the answer so that this question no longer shows up as "unanswered."

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use xquery/xpath to select all events where event/@date = "2015-08-28".

You use:

```
let $rawDoc := collection("/db/test")/data/schedules/schedule[event/@date = "2015-08-28"]
```

Which means, give me any `schedule` element that has at least one child `event` with that date.

Just change that to:

```
let $rawDoc := collection("/db/test")/data/schedules/schedule/event[@date = "2015-08-28"]
```

Which will give you all the event elements with that date.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the `schedule` elements and exclude all of it's `event` element children that do not have the desired date, your could do something like this:

```
let $rawDoc := collection("/db/test")/data/schedules/schedule

for $schedule in $rawDoc
return element { node-name($schedule) } {
    $schedule/@*,
    $schedule/node()[self::event[@date='2015-08-28'] | 
                                 self::text() | 
                                 self::processing-instruction() | 
                                 self::comment()]
}
```

Although, it might be easier to just select the desired `event` elements and return them inside of a `schedule` element:

```
let $rawDoc := collection("/db/test")/data/schedules/schedule/event[@date = "2015-08-28"]

for $event in $rawDoc
return <schedule>{$event}</schedule>
```

Comment: Thank you; I was under the misunderstanding that /schedule[event/@date] would select 'only', not 'any'. I wanted to capture the surrounding 'schedules/schedule' parent nodes in the output, hence the reason I initially decided to select on /schedule[event/@date] rather than /schedule/event[@date]. I appreciate that you provided a way for me to retain the parental nodes.

Comment: You might also consider selecting the relevant `schedules`, and then transforming the information with XSLT. It may be more simple/easy to use a modified identity transform to prune the unwanted content with a couple of empty templates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform